# TypeOrm inserts same row

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

Here is my entities class

```js
@Entity('leg')
export class Leg {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column() startDateTime: Date;
    @Column() endDateTime: Date;
    @Column() cost: number;
    @Column() price: number;

    @OneToOne( type => Station,{
        cascade: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    startStation: Station;

    @OneToOne( type => Station,{
        cascade: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    endStation: Station;

}

@Entity('station')
export class Station {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column() stationCode: string;
    @Column() lat: string;
    @Column() lng: string;
    @Column() publicNameShort: string;
    @Column() publicNameLong: string;

    @OneToOne( type => Address,{
        cascade: true,
    })
    @JoinColumn()
    address: Address;

}

@Entity('address')
export class Address {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @PrimaryColumn() line1: string;
    @PrimaryColumn() line2: string;
    @PrimaryColumn() country: string;
    @PrimaryColumn() state: string;
    @PrimaryColumn() zip: number;
    @PrimaryColumn() city: string;

    @OneToMany( type => Billing,
        billing => billing.address,)
    billings: Billing[];

}
```

When I insert a new leg, TypeOrm inserts a new address each time even if that address exists in the table.

[image: address table]

This is the address table I end up with. I do not want to insert the address if it exists.

Comment: removing auto generated id is not working. When i remove it, it generates an error when a registered address comes from the leg or station, it says 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "REL_3d48da9a43480e1b2b94042fb6"'

Comment: You missed a backtick at the end of the code block.